# Compare 2 arrays with powershell

Tags: powershell

I have 2 Arrays $UsersGroup and $UsersActive, i need to find where in $UsersActive i have a line with SamAccountName and the ObjectGUID .

$UsersGroup =

```
SamAccountName ObjectGUID
-------------- ----------
XXXX00XX       0031e949-9120-4df1-bddb-98067a141448
XXXX01XX       0031e949-9120-4df1-bdgb-99067a141448
XXXX02XX       0031e949-9120-4df1-bdab-97067a141448
```

and without headers

$UsersActive =

```
fcb483fa146b
fcb515739a2f
fcb82f1ef74c
fcc5ee8b8722
fcd3f1f471c2
fceb26a598a3
fd0b14cecd0e
98067a141448
```

I need to have the match user from $UsersActive to $UserGroup.Object like that

```
$UsersGroup | ForEach-Object {if($_.ObjectGUID -contains $UsersActive) {$_}}
```

But i don't get the result like that :

**XXXX00XX       0031e949-9120-4df1-bddb-98067a141448**

Can some one help me , thanks !

Comment: `$UsersGroup.Where{ $UserActive -Match $_.ObjectGUID.ToString() }`?

Comment: Misunderstanding of -contains vs .contains() is common, aside from $UsersActive being an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-contains` is a *collection containment* operator, testing for the exact occurrence of the right-hand side argument in the left-hand side argument.

To test for the presence of a substring in a string, use the `-like` wildcard string comparison operator:

```
$UsersGroup | Where-Object {
    $guid = $_.ObjectGUID
    $UsersActive.Where({$guid -like "*$_*"}, 'First')
}
```

Each group entry will now be tested against every `$UsersActive` value until a match is found (causing `Where-Object` to pass the object through) or no match is found (causing `Where-Object` to filter out the object)

Comment: Super thank you very much !!!! If i want a notlike , tried : `$UsersGroup | Where-Object {
    $guid = $_.ObjectGUID
    $UsersActive.Where({$guid -notlike "*$_*"})` but i have all content of $UserGroup :'(
}

Comment: @RaphaelGuillaume You mean the inverse? All objects where no match was found for the GUID in `$UsersActive`? Just prefix the `$UsersActive.Where({...})` expression with `-not`: `-not $UsersActive.Where({$guid -like "*$_*"}, 'First')`

Comment: @RaphaelGuillaume You're most welcome! If my answer solves your problem, please consider marking it "accepted" by clicking the checkmark on the left :)

Answer (score 0):

To offer an alternative solution:

As Mathias states in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73556360/45375), the [`-contains`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#-contains-and--notcontains) operator and its operands-reversed counterpart, [`-in`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#-in-and--notin), only perform *equality* comparison of a single comparison value against the elements of a collection (array).

- As an aside: Given that `$_.ObjectGUID` is the scalar (single object) and  `$UsersActive` the collection (array) to search in, you would have needed to use `-in`, not `-contains` (`$_.ObjectGUID -in $UsersActive`)

Unfortunately, as of version 7.3.2, PowerShell's *pattern-matching* operators, [`-like`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#-like) (with [wildcard expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Wildcards)) and [`-match`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#-match-and--notmatch) (with [regexes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Regular_Expressions)), do *not* support matching against *multiple* (an array of) patterns.

However, since you're looking to match a *literal substring* of each `.ObjectGUID` value, you *can* use `-in` if you extract that relevant substring first and use *it* as the comparison value:

```bash
# -> Object whose GUID is '0031e949-9120-4df1-bddb-98067a141448'
$usersGroup | Where-Object { ($_.ObjectGUID -split '-')[-1] -in $usersActive }
```

Note how the [`-split` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Split) is used to split the GUID into tokens by `-`, with `[-1]` returning the *last* token, which `-in` then looks for by equality comparison in the `$UsersActive` array.

---

As an aside:

- Allowing *multiple* patterns as the RHS of `-like` and `-match` - so as to return `$true` if *any* of them match - would be a helpful future improvement.
- [GitHub issue #2132](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/2132) asks for just that.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, using compare-object...  This has only one match.  Compare-object can be slow for large lists.

```
$usersgroup = 
'SamAccountName,ObjectGUID
XXXX00XX,0031e949-9120-4df1-bddb-98067a141448
XXXX01XX,0031e949-9120-4df1-bdgb-99067a141448
XXXX02XX,0031e949-9120-4df1-bdab-97067a141448' | convertfrom-csv

$usersactive = -split
'fcb483fa146b
fcb515739a2f
fcb82f1ef74c
fcc5ee8b8722
fcd3f1f471c2
fceb26a598a3
fd0b14cecd0e
98067a141448'

compare ($usersgroup.objectguid -replace '.*-') $usersactive -IncludeEqual |
  ? sideindicator -eq '=='  # order doesn't matter


InputObject  SideIndicator
-----------  -------------
98067a141448 ==
```